# can socket printf format

Tags: c, sockets, can-bus

I have a problem displaying my CAN ID . I'm sending out a message via the CAN bus , which has the ID 0x18FF11F3 . My program receives this message and also all data fields , only the ID does not match exactly

```
    void set_can_listener(uint16 *s16_Socket, struct can_frame *Frame) {
    /* Create the socket */
    *s16_Socket = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW);

    /* Locate the interface you wish to use */
    struct ifreq t_Ifr;
    strcpy(t_Ifr.ifr_name, "can0");
    ioctl(*s16_Socket, SIOCGIFINDEX, &t_Ifr); /* Ifr.ifr_ifindex gets filled with that device's index*/

    /* Select that CAN interface, and bind the socket to it.*/
    struct sockaddr_can t_Addr;
    t_Addr.can_family = AF_CAN;
    t_Addr.can_ifindex = t_Ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    bind(*s16_Socket, (struct sockaddr*) &t_Addr, sizeof(t_Addr));
}


void can_listener(uint16 *s16_Socket, struct can_frame *Frame) {
    /* Read message from CAN */
    unsigned int i;
    uint16 s16_BytesRead = read(*s16_Socket, Frame, sizeof(*Frame));
    if (s16_BytesRead >= 0) {
        printf("\nMessage received!\nID: 0x%X\nDLC: %X\n", Frame->can_id,
                Frame->can_dlc);
    }
}
```

My Output looks like:

```
Message received! 
ID: 0x98FF11F3 
DLC: 8
```

Comment: If read() returns zero you shouldn't be printing anything. Hard to believe a single bit got magically set somewhere. Are you sure you sent it correctly? Why isn't there proper error checking in this code? And what does this have to do with `primtf()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading ID with `CAN_EFF_FLAG` filter set, define as

```
#define CAN_EFF_FLAG 0x80000000U
```

[HERE](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/can.h?v=3.14)

The code is ok and received messages are ok. Sender has `EFF` filter enabled on the socket.

[THIS](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/networking/can.txt) link can explain you all about `SocketCAN`